# absolute position on table inside overflow scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom select list and inside that in the table, but absolute position in the select list not working in the table and fill height table, I want select list overly table and don't fill height

Table code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="main">
            <table class="table table-striped mytable">
                <thead class="bg-gradient-pink">
                <tr>
                    <th>title1</th>
                    <th>title2</th>
                    <th>title3</th>
                    <th>title4</th>


                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option>option1</option>
                            <option>option2</option>
                            <option>option3</option>

                            <option>option4</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>




                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
```

JS Code :

```
/*****Custom Selectbox*****/
function create_custom_dropdowns() {
    $('select').each(function(i, select) {
        if (!$(this).next().hasClass('mydropdown')) {
            $(this).after('<div class="mydropdown ' + ($(this).attr('class') || '') + '" tabindex="0"><span class="current"></span><div class="list"><ul></ul></div></div>');
            var dropdown = $(this).next();
            var options = $(select).find('option');
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
            dropdown.find('.current').html(selected.data('display-text') || selected.text());
            options.each(function(j, o) {
                var display = $(o).data('display-text') || '';
                dropdown.find('ul').append('<li class="option ' + ($(o).is(':selected') ? 'selected' : '') + '" data-value="' + $(o).val() + '" data-display-text="' + display + '">' + $(o).text() + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });
}

// Event listeners

// Open/close
    $(document).on('click', '.mydropdown', function(event) {
        $('.mydropdown').not($(this)).removeClass('open');
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).find('.option').attr('tabindex', 0);
            $(this).find('.selected').focus();
        } else {
            $(this).find('.option').removeAttr('tabindex');
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
// Close when clicking outside
    $(document).on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest('.mydropdown').length === 0) {
            $('.mydropdown').removeClass('open');
            $('.mydropdown .option').removeAttr('tabindex');
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
// Option click
    $(document).on('click', '.mydropdown .option', function(event) {
        $(this).closest('.list').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var text = $(this).data('display-text') || $(this).text();
        $(this).closest('.mydropdown').find('.current').text(text);
        $(this).closest('.mydropdown').prev('select').val($(this).data('value')).trigger('change');
    });

// Keyboard events
    $(document).on('keydown', '.mydropdown', function(event) {
        var focused_option = $($(this).find('.list .option:focus')[0] || $(this).find('.list .option.selected')[0]);
        // Space or Enter
        if (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                focused_option.trigger('click');
            } else {
                $(this).trigger('click');
            }
            return false;
            // Down
        } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).trigger('click');
            } else {
                focused_option.next().focus();
            }
            return false;
            // Up
        } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).trigger('click');
            } else {
                var focused_option = $($(this).find('.list .option:focus')[0] || $(this).find('.list .option.selected')[0]);
                focused_option.prev().focus();
            }
            return false;
            // Esc
        } else if (event.keyCode == 27) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).trigger('click');
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

        create_custom_dropdowns();
```

live version : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bofalo/79rpvfu6/1/)

(In the last row can see some gap added for select list )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove this added  gap in the last but it will appear again when opening the list to give the space to it.

The easy way to do it is by adding:

```
   transform: scale(0);
```

on the **.mydropdown .list** class

https://jsfiddle.net/ts81z0vg/

Comment: Thank you, no solution when opening?

Comment: I see, but no solution when opening?

Comment: it worked for me. when you are not opening the list no space will appear , but when you open it the space will be added for the list to appear.

Comment: yes, it worked, I mean we can not find any solution for when open it doesn't add space when appear?

Comment: the only solution is to put the div with the class="list" outside the div with the class="main". and make it absolute with the position of the mydropdown position, and add z-index to it.

Sorry For late to answer, i don't see your comment